# How to include non-Python dependencies in a Python Django deployment?

Tags: python, django, heroku, ta-lib

I am deploying a Django application using Heroku. One of my application's dependencies is the 'ta-lib' library, which is a Python wrapper for a library written in C. To get this to work locally, I simply had to download the underlying C library and the program would pick up what it needed from /usr/local and I had no problems.

Library reference: https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/install.html

Now, when I'm trying to push my files to Heroku via Git, the build fails at this library. Here is the terminal output, starting from where the errors began:

```
    remote:          Building wheel for TA-Lib (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for TA-Lib (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
remote:          ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:           command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ya1rkeoc/ta-lib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ya1rkeoc/ta-lib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-e83ejfm_
remote:               cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ya1rkeoc/ta-lib/
remote:          Complete output (27 lines):
remote:          /tmp/pip-install-ya1rkeoc/ta-lib/setup.py:71: UserWarning: Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.
remote:            warnings.warn('Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.')
remote:          running bdist_wheel
remote:          running build
remote:          running build_py
remote:          creating build
remote:          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
remote:          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:          copying talib/test_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:          copying talib/test_func.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:          copying talib/stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:          copying talib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:          copying talib/test_abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:          copying talib/abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:          copying talib/deprecated.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:          copying talib/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:          copying talib/test_stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:          running build_ext
remote:          building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
remote:          creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
remote:          creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:          gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/tmp/pip-install-ya1rkeoc/ta-lib/.eggs/numpy-1.20.3-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9 -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib/_ta_lib.o
remote:          talib/_ta_lib.c:611:10: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_defs.h: No such file or directory
remote:            611 | #include "ta-lib/ta_defs.h"
remote:                |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:          compilation terminated.
remote:          error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
remote:          ----------------------------------------
remote:          ERROR: Failed building wheel for TA-Lib
remote:          Running setup.py clean for TA-Lib
remote:          Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for wrapt: filename=wrapt-1.12.1-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl size=78588 sha256=bcbc0270be5d84ca062d30a118d3e1b5bb48b1eb96ca15d72db3ba00e95e33dc
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-xcx232so/wheels/98/23/68/efe259aaca055e93b08e74fbe512819c69a2155c11ba3c0f10
remote:        Successfully built lazy-object-proxy wrapt
remote:        Failed to build TA-Lib
remote:        Installing collected packages: asgiref, six, wrapt, lazy-object-proxy, astroid, certifi, chardet, Cython, pytz, sqlparse, Django, gunicorn, idna, isort, mccabe, numpy, urllib3, requests, pycoingecko, toml, pylint, TA-Lib, typed-ast
remote:            Running setup.py install for TA-Lib: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for TA-Lib: finished with status 'error'
remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ya1rkeoc/ta-lib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ya1rkeoc/ta-lib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-l9p7ava0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/TA-Lib
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ya1rkeoc/ta-lib/
remote:            Complete output (28 lines):
remote:            /tmp/pip-install-ya1rkeoc/ta-lib/setup.py:71: UserWarning: Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.
remote:              warnings.warn('Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.')
remote:            running install
remote:            running build
remote:            running build_py
remote:            creating build
remote:            creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
remote:            creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:            copying talib/test_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:            copying talib/test_func.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:            copying talib/stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:            copying talib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:            copying talib/test_abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:            copying talib/abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:            copying talib/deprecated.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:            copying talib/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:            copying talib/test_stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:            running build_ext
remote:            skipping 'talib/_ta_lib.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
remote:            building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
remote:            creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
remote:            creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
remote:            gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9 -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib/_ta_lib.o
remote:            talib/_ta_lib.c:611:10: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_defs.h: No such file or directory
remote:              611 | #include "ta-lib/ta_defs.h"
remote:                  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:            compilation terminated.
remote:            error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ya1rkeoc/ta-lib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ya1rkeoc/ta-lib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-l9p7ava0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/TA-Lib Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to <my-app-name>.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/<my-app-name>.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/<my-app-name>.git'enter code here
```

How do I determine which files from the underlying C library are needed and where do I add them to my Django project when pushing my code?

Thank you.

Comment: There is [TA-Lib buildpack for Heroku](https://github.com/numrut/heroku-buildpack-python-talib). Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, that is what ended up working! Thank you.